# Pimcore content editor removing <section> tags

Tags: wysiwyg, pimcore

I am working on [Pimcore](https://pimcore.com/en). In CMS I have created a page and added block to render Html on page. The page is working but, I am facing a problem that the Html editor in CMS is removing `<section>` tags while saving the Html. I couldn't find the function where it is saving the html. Tried to do some trick in its js file by adding section in allowedContent object `allowedContent:{"h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 table ul ol blockquote div tr p div li td section":{propertiesOnly:!0,attributes:"dir"}}`

but, It couldn't help it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pimcore HTML Editor is the CKEditor. To keep sections in the editor, you'll need to modify the CKEditor and add the section widget:
https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/section